# What tense after "I've never met ... who"?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-perfect, present-tense

I have some troubles with tenses after "I've never met  ...". Should it be in past or present? Or it doesn't really matter and I can go with whatever I feel like?

Some examples from Google:

> I've never met a Haitian who **isn't** strong

but

> I've never met a funny person who **wasn't** smart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either is fine.  This is a common question related to the present perfect, and isn't specific to "I've never met".  For example:

> I've always thought that funny people **were/are** smart.

I would say that the past tense is more common with "I've never met", since you're referring to people you have met in the past -- but this contrasts with the way English speakers like to use the present tense to talk about people who are still alive.

> Most funny people I've known **are** also pretty smart.

Which is to say, the past tense slightly implies they might not still be alive. For example:

> The men in my family **always were** at risk for heart disease.

In this sentence there's a subtle nuance that some of these men died from heart-related ailments.  If I want to avoid this implication, I could say:

> The men in my family **are** at risk for heart disease.

Still, don't overthink it. Sometimes people say things to convey subtle meanings.  Sometimes people say what's most common without thinking too deeply about it.

> I've never met an English student who **wasn't** frequently confused by all these seemingly contradictory language "rules".

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer. So if I'm, for example, talking about people I've never met, it's better to use past, because I can't imply whether they are alive or dead since I've never met them, right?

Comment: @XDeath Well, when you say *"I've never met an X who wasn't Y"*, you are actually saying, *"I've met a lot of Xs and all of them were Y"*.  So yes, you can use the past tense to describe people you have met in the past.  However, if you are really talking about some quality of people you have *never* met, use the subjunctive:  "I've never met a computer programmer, but if I did I imagine he **would be** a fan of *Star Trek*"